# UPDATE with WHERE CLAUSE returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause

Basically I need to populate my temp table with dates from another table but in a specific order which has already been ordered (visit_cnt) in the original (data) table....

**#PIVOT (data table)

```
Member id    name     first_service_date        visit_cnt**
05465         matt               11/13                 2
05465         matt               9/12                  1
64985         mark               12/13                 2
64985         mark               8/13                  1
```

WCV_TEMP (temp)
I need my table to look like this. Only single records with multiple dates…

```
Member id    name      visit1     visit2    visit3  
05465        matt        7/12      3/13      8/13
64965        mark        9/11      5/12      2/13
78995        luke        12/10     5/12      7/13
```

FIGURED I UPDATE EACH COLUMN IN SECOND TABLE WITH WHERE CLAUSE

```
UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1 
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =1 

UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_2 
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_2= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =2 

UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_3 
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_3= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =3

UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_5
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_5= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =4

UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_5 
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_5= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =5
```

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: `first_service_date` vs `[FIRST SERVICE DATE]` ?

Comment: typo the column is titled first service date and needs to be in brackets for statements...

Comment: What are you asking?  Is something not working, or are you getting an error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. "returns error" is not a sufficient description of any problem. Instead, you should explain exactly what error you are getting, and reduce your question to exactly the query you are having troubles with (you have five examples in the question as it stands now)

Comment: You aren't `Join`ing the `#Pivot` table in your `Update` statement.

Comment: Cannot use the column prefix 'WCV_TEMP'. This must match the object in the UPDATE clause 'WCV_TEMP.VISIT_2'. ERROR

Comment: both tables have already been joined by memberid... SELECT DISTINCT #PIVOT.MEMBERID,#PIVOT.NAME, #PIVOT.DOB, WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1, WCV_TEMP.VISIT_2,WCV_TEMP.VISIT_3, WCV_TEMP.VISIT_4, WCV_TEMP.VISIT_5 FROM #PIVOT LEFT JOIN WCV_TEMP ON #PIVOT.MEMBERID = WCV_TEMP.MEMBERID

Comment: this is the basic query that retrns the error @lc             UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1 
SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT =1

Comment: Why not just use the `pivot` command?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `Join` to your temp table.  Try something like this:

```
Update  W 
Set     VISIT_1 = P.[FIRST SERVICE DATE]
From    WCV_TEMP    W
Join    #PIVOT      P On P.[Member Id] = W.[Member Id]
Where   P.VISIT_CNT = 1
```

And similar for your other `Update` statements.

Comment: @SIYUL is the W and P in your FROM and JOIN lines supposed to there?

Comment: @SIYUL this returns the same error:                            Cannot use the column prefix 'WCV_TEMP'. This must match the object in the UPDATE clause 'WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1'.
                                                               UPDATE WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1 SET WCV_TEMP.VISIT_1= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] FROM WCV_TEMP JOIN #PIVOT ON #PIVOT.UNIVERSALMEMBERID= WCV_TEMP.UNIVERSALMEMBERID WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT= 1

Comment: Yes, the W and P are supposed to be there.  And that query looks nothing like what I provided.

Comment: just ran the query and got this error... the visit1 column was created as an (int) maybe it should be (datetime)? Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type int, table 'QM.AFFINITY\INwafor.WCV_TEMP', column 'VISIT_1'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Update  W 
Set     VISIT_1 = P.[FIRST SERVICE DATE]
From    WCV_TEMP    W
Join    #PIVOT      P On P.[UNIVERSALMEMBERID] = W.[UNIVERSALMEMBERID]
Where   P.VISIT_CNT = 1

Comment: I don't know the structure of your data - you'll have to modify it to fit the situation.

Comment: So this query gets the job done...however since VISIT_1 IS (INT) AND [FIRST SERVICE DATE] IS DATETIME... I NEED TO INCLUDE A CONVERT STATEMENT...not sure where though...

UPDATE WCV_TEMP
SET VISIT_1= #PIVOT.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] 
FROM WCV_TEMP
JOIN #PIVOT ON #PIVOT.UNIVERSALMEMBERID= WCV_TEMP.UNIVERSALMEMBERID
WHERE #PIVOT.VISIT_CNT= 1

Comment: error: Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type int. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You can try to do a `Convert`, but this sounds like a bad idea.  It sounds more like you're trying to force a value into a field.  You should probably review your table structure so that the column you're trying to update is the type you're actually wanting it to be.

Comment: thanks your awesome! I dropped my visit columns and added them but this time with datetime formate reran my query and it ran!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 4-5 separate update statements you can put all this inside one update statement using CASE statement something like this....

```
Update  W 
Set  W.VISIT1 = CASE 
                    WHEN  P.VISIT_CNT = 1  
                    THEN  P.[FIRST_SERVICE_DATE]
                 END
    ,W.VISIT2 = CASE 
                   WHEN  P.VISIT_CNT = 2  
                   THEN  P.[FIRST_SERVICE_DATE]
                 END  
    ,W.VISIT3 = CASE 
                   WHEN  P.VISIT_CNT = 3  
                   THEN  P.[FIRST_SERVICE_DATE]
                 END          
    ,W.VISIT4 = CASE 
                   WHEN  P.VISIT_CNT = 4  
                   THEN  P.[FIRST_SERVICE_DATE]
                 END

From    WCV_TEMP W INNER JOIN #PIVOT P 
On P.[Member Id] = W.[Member Id]
```

Comment: the single "w" and "p" in the last FROM statment is that supposed to be there...im very new to sql so not sure what these are

Comment: These are Table Aliases , rather then using full names of tables again and again I have used these table aliases to reference table names.

Comment: I get this error: The column prefix '#PIVOT' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.